# How to update an array of object with a dynamic index?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, unity-game-engine

## START

**ex "Array resized lost class or index"**

I am building an object that saves the values ​​of my car.

The basic logic is:
For each gearbox > save every suspension > save every wheel.

The logic of script:

```
  public class VehicleController : MonoBehaviour
  {
      public gearbox[] gearboxes = new gearbox[0]; //999 not change effect

      [System.Serializable] 
      public class gearbox
      {
        public Transform gearBoxTarget;

        public List<Transform> assets = new List<Transform>();

        public gearbox(Transform gearBoxTarget, List<Transform> assets  )
        {
            this.gearBoxTarget = gearBoxTarget;
            this.assets = assets;
        }
      }

      void Awake()
      {
        /// count all gBox into 3d model
        List<Transform> boxes = new List<Transform>();
        Transform[] elems = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        int Index = 0;
        for (int c = 0; c < elems.Length; c++)
        {
          if (elems[c].name == "gearbox")
          {
            Index++;
            boxes.Add(elems[c].transform);
          }
        }

        /// set array length (1 for gBox finded)
        System.Array.Resize(ref gearboxes, Index);

        /// for all gearboxes finded (or boxes.Length... It's equal)
        for (int box = 0; box < gearboxes.Length; box++)
        {
          // get suspansions and wheels
          Transform[] inBox = boxes[box].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
          List <Transform> Items = new List <Transform>();
          for (int e = 0; e < inBox.Length; e++)
          {
              var el = inBox[e];
              if (el.parent.name == "gearbox" || el.name == "wheel"){ Debug.Log(e+" => "+el); Items.Add(el); }else{Debug.Log(e);}
              if(e==inBox.Length) { Debug.Log("finder end"); }
          }

          /// add elements into the gearbox object
          Debug.Log(gearboxes[box]); // NULL!
          gearboxes[box].gearBoxTarget = boxes[box]; // NULL!
          gearboxes[box].assets.AddRange(Items); // NULL!
        }
      }
  }
```

I don't understand why the length of the array has changed, the script seems to no longer see gearbox despite the fact that the inspector has been updated.

Whatever you try to put in, the gearbox... is null

---

## **TEST 02**

New simplified test.

I try to initialize the list in Awake.

It also creates a second list where the elements will be processed.

Failing to instantiate the object directly I try to transfer everything from a new list to the old one.

```
  public class VehicleController : MonoBehaviour
  {

    public gearbox[] gearboxes;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class gearbox
    {

      public Transform boxtarget; 

        public gearbox( Transform boxtarget  )
        {
        this.boxtarget = boxtarget;
        }
    
    }

    void Awake()
    {

        // count all gBox and set it on inspector and add to list
        Transform[] elems = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        List<Transform> targets = new List<Transform>();
        for (int c = 0; c < elems.Length; c++)
        {
          if (elems[c].name == "gearbox")
          {
            targets.Add(elems[c]);
          }
        }

        int Counter = targets.Count;

        // System.Array.Resize(ref gearboxes, Index);
        gearbox[] gboxes = new gearbox[Counter];
        gearboxes = new gearbox[Counter];

        for (int i = 0; i < Counter; ++i)
        { 

          Debug.Log(targets[i]); //ok exist
          gboxes[i].boxtarget = targets[i];
        }

        System.Array.Copy(gboxes, 0, gearboxes , 0, Counter);
         

    }

  }
```

Another fail.
In inspector list is update to 3 elements but is empty and debug write null.

> gearbox (UnityEngine.Transform) (targets ok)

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object VehicleControllerManager.VehicleController.Awake () (at

---

## **TEST 03**

**another approach ...**

The attempt now is to add a class to the list and retrieve the object in possession of that class.

That way I should bypass the fact that mono points directly to the gearboxes but sees it as an additional object.

```
public class VehicleController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public List<gearbox> gearboxes = new List<gearbox>();

    [System.Serializable] 
    public class gearbox
    {
      public class box
      {
        public Transform boxTarget;
        public box(Transform boxTarget)
        {
          this.boxTarget = boxTarget;
        }
      }
    }

    void Awake()
    {


      /// count all gBox into 3d model
      List<Transform> boxes = new List<Transform>();
      Transform[] elms = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
      int Counted = 0;
      for (int c = 0; c < elms.Length; c++)
      {
        if (elms[c].name == "gearbox")
        { Counted++; boxes.Add(elms[c].transform); }
      }

      Debug.Log(boxes.Count); // yes, it's 3

      /// add class on link (1 for all gBox finded)
      for (int box = 0; box < boxes.Count; box++)
      {
        gearboxes.Add( new VehicleController.gearbox()); // ok, added it
      }

      /// for all gearboxes in list
      for (int i = 0; i < gearboxes.Count; i++)
      {
        /// into the gearboxes get object and set values of box
        //gearboxes[i].gearbox.box.boxTarget = boxes[i]; WTF? I can't navigate into the class!??
      }

    }
}
```

Result: 3 Elements appear in the inspector but they seem to have nothing inside or, anyway ... `"gearboxes[i].gearbox.box.boxTarget = boxes[i];"` I can't navigate into the class...

will it be possible to recover boxes and set their internal values?

---

## **TEST 03.b**

Following the various suggestions and examples I found a ***"half solution"***.

It is not definitive because I do not display the content in the inspector but only the inserted class.

However, if I loop ... the data exists and is returned!

```
public class VehicleController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]        public List<gearbox> gearboxes = new List<gearbox>();
    [System.Serializable]   public class gearbox
                            {
                              public _box box = new _box();
                              [System.Serializable]
                              public class _box
                              {
                                public Transform boxTarget { get; set; }
                              }
                            }
  

    void Start()
    {


      /// count all gBox into 3d model
      List<Transform> boxes = new List<Transform>();
      Transform[] elms = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
      int Counted = 0;
      for (int c = 0; c < elms.Length; c++)
      {
        if (elms[c].name == "gearbox")
        { Counted++; boxes.Add(elms[c].transform); }
      }

      Debug.Log(boxes.Count);

      /// add class on link (1 for all gBox finded)
      for (int box = 0; box < boxes.Count; box++)
      {
        gearboxes.Add( new VehicleController.gearbox());
      }

      // for all gearboxes in list
      for (int i = 0; i < gearboxes.Count; i++)
      {
        /// add elements into the gearbox object
        gearboxes[i].box.boxTarget = boxes[i];
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < gearboxes.Count; i++)
      {
        Debug.Log("++ "+gearboxes[i].box.boxTarget);
      }

    }
}
```

---

## **TEST 03.c - SOLUTION**

As suggested it was to "instantiate the object" however *this was instantiated directly to the construction of the list*.

Without this the big problem was to understand that "IT ISN'T POSSIBLE TO INSTANT THE OBJECT IF IT IS EMPTY" or you will find the famous "null error".

So ... let's give it a null! :D and here is the solution!

```
public class VehicleController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]        public List<boxvalues> gearboxes = new List<boxvalues>();
    [System.Serializable]   public class boxvalues
                            {
                              public Transform boxTarget;
                              public boxvalues(Transform boxTarget)
                              {
                                this.boxTarget = boxTarget;
                              }
                              // [SerializeField] public Transform boxTarget { get; set; } // This is a safer system but does not expose variables.
                            }
  

    void Awake()
    {


      /// count all gBox into 3d model
      List<Transform> boxes = new List<Transform>();                       // prepare a list of gameObject.
      Transform[] elms = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();   // find all child into main gameObject.
      int Counted = 0;                                                     // Counter of gameObject
      for (int c = 0; c < elms.Length; c++)                                // Loop all finded gameObject into main
      {
        if (elms[c].name == "gearbox")                                     // if is my gameObject...
        { Counted++; boxes.Add(elms[c].transform); }                       // add it to list and count it...
      }

      Debug.Log(boxes.Count);                                              // yes, It's 3 gameObject.

      /// add class on link (1 for all gBox finded)
      for (int box = 0; box < boxes.Count; box++) 
      {
        gearboxes.Add( new VehicleController.boxvalues(null));            // now for all gameObject init a new data container... empty (yooo! new list of data!)
      }

      // for all gearboxes in list
      for (int i = 0; i < gearboxes.Count; i++)                           // now for all data container... put a new values. Win!
      {
        /// add elements into the box object
        gearboxes[i].boxTarget = boxes[i];
      }

      // test return the values
      for (int i = 0; i < gearboxes.Count; i++)
      {
        Debug.Log("++ "+gearboxes[i].boxTarget);
      }

    }
}
```

I sincerely thank those who have had the patience to give me a useful direction!

I hope this scheme is didactically useful to others.

Comment: If `gearbox` is a class then the default value of it is `null` - you need to create instances of that class if you want it to be non-null

Comment: but isn't it already instantiated as an array?
public gearbox[] gearboxes = new gearbox[0]; //999 not change effect

Comment: If `gearbox` is a `class` then you have an array of references to `gearbox` instances. The default value of such a reference is `null`

Comment: ok, however I don't understand why if I start giving the array a length this is instantiated and taken. If I try to make it start from 0 this disappears... The goal is to make the length adaptable.

Comment: maybe I understood. Should I loop through the new array and instantiate it again for each index? otherwise the idex is empty. Is this the logic?

Comment: @Alberto You cannot resize an array in c#, only replace it with a new one of a different size.  You should perhaps look into using List as this will provide ability to add/remove items.

Comment: @Tintow of course it is possible ... "System.Array.Resize(ref gearboxes, Index);" 
The problem is that then it is no longer connected to anything and I don't know why!

Comment: @Alberto  Array.Resize does NOT resize an array, it creates a new array at the requested size and copies the elements from the old array into it.  It's a technical point but an important one because the array is no longer the same object.

Comment: @Alberto, I think the issue is as UnholySheep explained, you are creating an array of the correct size but all of it's entries are null because you never set them to anything.

Comment: @Tintow Ah.......

Maybe that's why he can't find anything anymore. Because existence remains in the old array.
What the heck how can I build is what ??? How do I create a replicable model to put in an array then?

Comment: @Alberto it doesn't look like gearboxes[] ever contains anything.  If you breakpoint at your for loop and inspect gearboxes[] do any of the array elements actually contain anything other than null?

Comment: @Tintow the loop stops as soon as it tries to insert the found transform.
Therefore the array should not be empty (or in any case find everything I ask for) it is the object itself that is untied and not replaced.

I updated the post

Comment: **Arrays don't actually resize!** What happens is a new array is created, the old elements are copied, and then the reference is updated. If you have _other references_ to the same original array, the framework doesn't know about those. If you have an array where the size needs to change, that's what generic Lists are for.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  Yes ... it was understood. The question now is "how do I rebuild an array of objects and put it in the inspector?"

Answer (score 1):

You need to create instance of class:

```
public class VehicleController : MonoBehaviour
  {
      public gearbox[] gearboxes = null;

      public VehicleController()
      {
        gearboxes = new gearbox[0];
      }

      [System.Serializable] 
      public class gearbox
      {
        public Transform gearBoxTarget;

        public List<Transform> assets = new List<Transform>();

        public gearbox(Transform gearBoxTarget, List<Transform> assets  )
        {
            this.gearBoxTarget = gearBoxTarget;
            this.assets = assets;
        }
      }

      void Awake()
      {
        /// count all gBox into 3d model
        List<Transform> boxes = new List<Transform>();
        Transform[] elems = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        int Index = 0;
        for (int c = 0; c < elems.Length; c++)
        {
          if (elems[c].name == "gearbox")
          {
            Index++;
            boxes.Add(elems[c].transform);
          }
        }

        /// set array length (1 for gBox finded)
        System.Array.Resize(ref gearboxes, Index);

        /// for all gearboxes finded (or boxes.Length... It's equal)
        for (int box = 0; box < gearboxes.Length; box++)
        {
          // get suspansions and wheels
          Transform[] inBox = boxes[box].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
          List <Transform> Items = new List <Transform>();
          for (int e = 0; e < inBox.Length; e++)
          {
              var el = inBox[e];
              if (el.parent.name == "gearbox" || el.name == "wheel"){ Debug.Log(e+" => "+el); Items.Add(el); }else{Debug.Log(e);}
              if(e==inBox.Length) { Debug.Log("finder end"); }
          }

          /// add elements into the gearbox object
          Debug.Log(gearboxes[box]);
          gearboxes[box].gearBoxTarget = boxes[box];
          gearboxes[box].assets.AddRange(Items);
        }
      }
  }
```

I guess the function you don't add must be something like this:

```
public class Transform
    {

        public string name { get; set; }

        public Transform parent { get; set; }

        public Transform[] GetComponentsInChildren<T>()
        {
            return (new List<Transform>() {
                new Transform() { name = "gearbox" },
                new Transform() { parent = new Transform() { name = "gearbox" }, name = "wheel" }
            }).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Assuming that's the case, it's the same logic, you have to initialize the variable since you initialize the class or it will always be null.

```
public class VehicleController
    {
        private gearbox[] gearboxes;
        private readonly Transform transform;

        public VehicleController(Transform _transform)
        {
            gearboxes = new gearbox[0];
            transform = _transform;
        }

        [System.Serializable]
        public class gearbox
        {
            public Transform gearBoxTarget;

            public List<Transform> assets = new List<Transform>();

            public gearbox(Transform gearBoxTarget, List<Transform> assets)
            {
                this.gearBoxTarget = gearBoxTarget;
                this.assets = assets;
            }
        }

        void Awake()
        {
            /// count all gBox into 3d model
            List<Transform> boxes = new List<Transform>();
            Transform[] elems = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
            int Index = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < elems.Length; c++)
            {
                if (elems[c].name == "gearbox")
                {
                    Index++;
                    boxes.Add(elems[c].transform);
                }
            }

            /// set array length (1 for gBox finded)
            System.Array.Resize(ref gearboxes, Index);

            /// for all gearboxes finded (or boxes.Length... It's equal)
            for (int box = 0; box < gearboxes.Length; box++)
            {
                // get suspansions and wheels
                Transform[] inBox = boxes[box].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
                List<Transform> Items = new List<Transform>();
                for (int e = 0; e < inBox.Length; e++)
                {
                    var el = inBox[e];
                    if (el.parent.name == "gearbox" || el.name == "wheel") { Debug.Log(e + " => " + el); Items.Add(el); } else { Debug.Log(e); }
                    if (e == inBox.Length) { Debug.Log("finder end"); }
                }

                /// add elements into the gearbox object
                Debug.Log(gearboxes[box]);
                gearboxes[box].gearBoxTarget = boxes[box];
                gearboxes[box].assets.AddRange(Items);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No ... it doesn't work. keeps saying that gearboxes is null

Comment: What does function "transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>()" do?

Comment: recovers the objects in the container.
then they scan the name and, if it is called as the object, then I save it and count it.

to every object 3d would correspond the relative object c #

Comment: Anyway wait ... I publish the test 3 and I study what you recommended and I answer (I had not noticed that you updated the answer, I was also seeing for the get / set)

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't work this time either. He always says that gearboxes [box] is null.

Look at test 3, tell me what you think.

:(

Comment: I really thank you, without your example I would not have been able to understand and take the right way.